# Compiling issues

Tags: compiling

I made my a latex file on Kile in Ubuntu. The script that I used was

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{Hello, Cruel World!}
\author{Obedient Grad Student}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
This is where you tell people why they should bother reading your article.

\section{Literature Review}
This is the section that is invariably much longer than it should be, and
where everyone tries to impress peers about how easy it is to locate various
references in online databases.

\section{Conclusion}
Not much of a paper, but it's a start.

\end{document}
```

The first problem is that the title and the text start on the same line. The title and the author are on the same line. 
Secondly the documentclass is getting pinted i.e. the article starts with the word article!

Hope someone can help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Looks like you have problems with `TeX` installation. I have no problem compiling it in Ubuntu 14.04 with `TeX` distributed with it.

Comment: You are probably trying to compile with `pdftex` instead of `pdflatex` (and getting tons of errors). Check the building options in Kile.

Answer (score 6):

As @egreg commented above, make sure you compile with `pdflatex` rather than `pdftex` - this is what your example looks like when I compile it with `pdflatex`:

[image]

**For Comparison**

compiling with `pdftex` gives exactly the output described by the OP

[image]

Comment: In as much does this answer the question of the OP?

Comment: in that the given example - when compiled with `pdflatex` - is fine and gives the expected output. @egreg seems on the right path with his comment - I'll incorporate that into my answer to make it more useful.